# How do I get access to an outer variable in a closure in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following dynamically created class that is passed into the xpath function of nokogiri:

```
country = nil

ret = parent.xpath(".//text()[regex(.)]", Class.new{
  def regex(node_set, lead)
    result = node_set.find_all do |node|
      node.text =~ POST_CODE_EXPRESSION || node.text =~ ZIP_CODE_EXPRESSION
    end
    result
  end
}.new)
```

I would like to somehow access or set the country variable or get access to the outer self from within the regex function.

Is there anyway I can pass the outer self into the Class.new expression or can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods cannot be closures in Ruby, only blocks can:

```
country = nil

ret = parent.xpath(".//text()[regex(.)]", Class.new{
  define_method(:regex) do |node_set, lead|
    result = node_set.find_all do |node|
      node.text =~ POST_CODE_EXPRESSION || node.text =~ ZIP_CODE_EXPRESSION
    end
    result
  end
}.new)
```

By the way: your `regex` method is much more complicated than it needs to be. It's simply equivalent to

```
define_method(:regex) do |node_set, lead|
  node_set.find_all do |node|
    node.text =~ POST_CODE_EXPRESSION || node.text =~ ZIP_CODE_EXPRESSION
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
x = 1
Class.new do
  def initialize(binding)
    eval 'x += 1', binding
  end
end.new binding
p x # will print 2
```

It doesn't look very nice with eval but it works=)